# delete node after specified node in doubly linked list. (recursively)

Tags: java

I have this recursive function that is supposed to delete the node that comes after the specified one in
a doubly linked list. However My method Isn't deleting anything. I am having trouble with rearranging the values in the list. Any ideas?

```java
private void deleteAfterThis(T data, Node headAux) {
    if(headAux == null) {
        return;
    }

    Node deleteAfter = new Node(data);
    Node target = deleteAfter.next;
    if(target == null) {
        return;
    }

    if(deleteAfter.prev == null){
        if(target != tail && target==headAux) {
            deleteAfter.next = target.next;
            target.next.prev = deleteAfter;
            size--;
            deleteAfterThis(data, headAux.next);
        }

        else if(target == tail && target == headAux) {
            deleteAfter.next = null;
            deleteAfter = tail;
            size--;
            return;
        }
    }

    else if(deleteAfter.prev != null) {
        if(target != tail && target == headAux) {
            deleteAfter.next = target.next;
            target.next.prev = deleteAfter;
            size--;
            deleteAfterThis(data, headAux.next);
        }
        else if( target == tail && target == headAux) {
            deleteAfter.next = null;
            deleteAfter = tail;
            size--;
            return;
        }
    }

    deleteAfterThis(data, headAux.next);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One mistake I see right off the bat is that you should *not* be creating a completely new node for `deleteAfter`. Intuitively, does it make sense to have to create a new node when attempting to delete one? I'll assume that, even knowing what the constructor for `Node` actually looks like, it sets the `next` and `prev` pointers to nodes to `null`. As a result, you'll keep recursively updating `headAux` until it's `null` without ever deleting anything. It seems what you *want* `deleteAfter` to be is `headAux.next`.

Another bug I see is that you've copy and pasted your checking logic twice - I recommend stepping through both cases and verifying if the logic should be identical within each block of the `if` and `else-if` blocks (it probably shouldn't).

Stepping into the logic, you should realize that the `prev` node of the current (`headAux` in your code) would be `null` only if `headAux` is the `head` of the list. Thus, it would be a bit more clear to rewrite the `headAux.prev` check as verifying if `headAux` is equal to the `head` of the linked list.

Looking at the actual deletion logic, it seems to make sense in the general case to me (assuming the fact that `deleteAfter` is the `next` node of `headAux` as stated above). You're making the `prev` of the node to be deleted to point to the deleted node's `prev` node and the `next` of the previous node (after having set the pointer, which I'm not too big of a fan of but it works) point to `deleteAfter`.

Lastly, when you do actually locate the node you'd like to delete, you probably shouldn't be calling the recursive function again. You already handle the setting of pointers correctly, so there shouldn't be a need to do so.

I would *highly* recommend you (re-)draw a sample use-case of your circular linked list and perform deletion on a sheet of paper before jumping to coding the edgecases (which aren't all handled here). The edge cases you should probably be aware of are the following: empty list, deleting head, deleting tail, single-node list. In your code, it seems that you did try to handle the deletion of the head (you'd have to remember to set the head afterwards). After getting that to work, making deletion work on other cases should be a breeze.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I also think that I need to clarify that I'm supposed to be removing the node that comes after the one with the specified data element. That's why I thought I had to keep track of the node that contains that data via a new node. But now I'm not sure how to check if the node with the specified data is even in the list

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying! Your logic seems to make a bit more sense then. What you should do in that case is check if the *existing* next node contains the specified data instead of creating a new node. If the next node does *not* contain it, then you'd call your recursive function to continue onwards. You're handling the base case correctly, and if the current node `headAux` is `null`, you terminate without having done anything.

Comment: Ok so I've updated my method. I thought it would make more sense to just go down the list and see if the parameter node 's data is equal to the specified data and then delete.    private void deleteAfterThis(T data, Node headAux) {
  if(headAux == null) {
   return;
  }
  
  if(headAux.data == data){
       if(headAux.next != null) {
        headAux.next = headAux.next.next;
        size--;
    deleteAfterThis(data, headAux.next); 
       }
  }
   
  deleteAfterThis(data, headAux.next);

 }

Comment: Hmm... it's kinda hard to read the code without formatting but it's almost correct. Since you're working with a double linked list, you need to make sure that the node after the deleted one has a `prev` pointer back to `headAux`.
I suppose that your intention is to perform this 'node after' deletion for any node containing `data`, so what you must can do is remove the call `deleteAfterThis` *after deleting*, as you're calling the recursive function too many times.
Other than that, you just need to add in special logic for the edge cases (deleting the tail for example).